# "Element invalid at this location" error in call to Apex web service

Tags: soap-api, webservices, apex-webservice

I am getting SessionID invalid after taking session id from visualforce page using {!$Api.Session_ID}

I am getting the below response from workbench
Element {https://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/SoapWebservice_BookPlanner}SessionID invalid at this location

[image]

[image]

Comment: That appears to be a SOAP error, not an indication that the Session ID itself is invalid. Could you please share more context and/or code?

Comment: My request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
   xmlns:amit="https://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/SoapWebservice_BookPlanner">
 <soapenv:Header>
  <amit:SessionHeader>
    <amit:SessionID>...Session ID...</amit:SessionID>
  </amit:SessionHeader>
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
   <amit:createBook>
    <amit:BookName>SoapBook1</amit:BookName>
   </amit:createBook>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: Please edit your question rather than posting code in comments.

Comment: check screenshot.Anything else you need let me know @David Reed

Comment: I don't personally know the answer to this question. We generally encourage you to post **code** and verbatim error messages in the body of your question. Screenshots are harder to use to interpret code issues.

Comment: I'm far from an expert on SOAP but this trailhead seems to have some good examples. Your code does not match these examples so that's where I would start: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/api_basics/api_basics_soap

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the element needs to be sessionId, not SessionID as you've written here. Pay attention when working with raw XML, as everything is case sensitive.

See [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/66511) for an example SOAP message.

Comment: Now sessionId isssue has gone.But I am getting the below issue in response
<faultstring>No operation available for request {http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/SoapWebservice_BookPlanner}createBook</faultstring>

Comment: @L2018 Try using SoapUI or another tool to generate a *correct* request. You would save yourself a lot of trouble. I suspect you may need a `<amit:data>` element to wrap your parameter. If you try SoapUI and still get stuck, please post a new question instead of editing an existing question. Also, next time, **please** use plain text code instead of a picture. It makes it a lot more challenging to work with.